# how to retrieve model name from relationship name of a given defined model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Say I have a model App\Models\User in which I define a relationship `child` with model App\Models\User. Meaning another user can be a child of given user.

Now I want to retrieve the value of model-name refered to by relationship `child`. Answer: App\Models\User

how to do that in Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get full name with namespace :

```
$className = get_class($user->child()->getRelated());
```

To get just the base name :

```
$baseClass = class_basename($className);
```